# linux device driver for pure ipv6 device

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, ipv6

I am currently designing a linux driver for a pure IPv6 driver. Is there any way to make the kernel module only support IPv6 and can only be assigned IPv6 address? What is the commands in linux to set the address?

Thanks

Comment: A pure IPv6 driver for what? Network devices are sent packets; they shouldn't care what version of IP is being used with them, or, for that matter, whether the packet contains IP data at all.

Comment: Hmm, aren't you confused about layering in the stack? Why is your device even concerned with L3 stuff?

Comment: Yes, the device is just sending binary data. However, I just want to limit my device cannot have a IPv4 address. And perhaps, perform in the IPv6 manner and never response to incoming IPv4 packet.Any idea?

Comment: your device driver should worry about PPP or Ethernet or whatever low-level protocol your device talks. What gets put on top of Ethernet (or PPP) is entirely at the discretion of the layer above the device driver and is none of your business as a driver author.

Comment: Don't worry about IPv4, IPv6, or even any protocol above the link layer technology you are working with *unless* your device provides specific hardware capabilities for working with payload like checksumming, filtering, or what not. And even those are usually exposed to upper layers as just configuration nobs for tools like `ethtool` to play with.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding IP:**

Using `ip` command:

```
$sudo /sbin/ip -6 addr add 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64 dev eth0
```

Using `ifconfig` command:

```
$sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64
```

**Deleting IP:**

Using `ip`

```
$sudo /sbin/ip -6 addr del 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64 dev eth0
```

Using `ifconfig`

```
$sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 del 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64
```